# Testing a function that passes a parameter to onClick props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component `Header` which has an `action` prop which has an onClick event handler which calls a function with a parameter status. Example :

```
    // App.tsx
     /// React imports
  const App = () => {
     let status = new B()
    
     const someFunc = (val) => {
      if (val instanceof A) {
        console.log('inside A')
      } else if (val instanceof B) {
        console.log('Inside B')
      } else {
        console.log('No matchers')
      }
    }
    return (
         <>
           <Header id="someID" action={{ text: 'Change', onClick: () => somefunc(status) }} /> 
         </>);
     }
```

I am writing a unit test to simulate onClick to have been called with status like this :

```
 // App.test.js


describe("test", ()=>{
      it('simulate click', () => {
       const createComponent = () => (<App />)
        const status = new A()
        const wrapper = mount(createComponent())
    
        wrapper
          .find('#someID')
          .simulate('click', {status: status})
    
        expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('inside A') // expected 'Inside B'
      })
    })
```

Somehow, it is still catching the status defined in `App.tsx` and not in the test file. Where could I be wrong?

PS: I know we should not business implementation in React, but I have the necessity to test business implementation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the `createComponent` function? What are you testing? Provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ```createComponent``` is ideally a component which creates a component. I've used multiple Providers So I've not added that. For simplicity ```createComponent()``` would return ```<App />``` component.

Comment: I mean we need to know what component did you render and the code of the component so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

The onClick handler is defined as

`onClick: () => somefunc(status)` not as

`onClick: (status) => somefunc(status)` or even

`onClick: (event) => somefunc(event.target.value)` or somesuch.

So yes, the lambda has captured the status of the component and enshrined it permanently in the little function.

Comment: This is what I am doing at ```onClick: () => somefunc(status)```, how do I make it testable depending on the instance the onClick is called with? Is there some changes I have to make in testing?. Also I can't edit onClick handler as i'm importing the ```<Header>``` component which expects return type of ```() => void```